# Converting a category on UIViewController into a custom subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, subclass, iboutlet

I had a class category that adds some methods to `UIViewController`. I needed to add some instance variables to the category, so I turned it into a custom `UIViewController` subclass, and added the instance variables. I then turned the `UIViewController` I was displaying into an instance of the new subclass.

Now I'm having trouble loading the new `UIViewController` when the application loads. I load the view controller from a nib in my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ATFIPresentationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ATFIPresentationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; //Crashes Here
    return YES;
}
```

After doing so, an exception is thrown when I call `makeKeyAndVisible` on my application's window:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<ATFIPresentationViewController 0x6c497d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key basicPicker.'
```

Where basicPicker is an `IBOutlet` to a `UITextField`. This is happening for every `IBOutlet` I've defined in my viewController. Why would making my viewController a subclass of my subclass of `UIViewController`, prevent anything loading from my nib? The "Files Owner" in the nib is ViewController, not `ATFIPresentationViewController`.

EDIT: Well, I got tired of trying to get this to work the "proper" and less typing heavy way. I got it to work by turning the extension into an NSObject, and pass the UIViewController to it. I posted what I was using this for on [gitHub](https://github.com/Marxon13/Easy-Alternitive-UITextField-Input) if anyone wants to take a look.

Comment: Do you have outlets to ivars or to properties?

Comment: I've tried both, and they produce the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: Nope, I saw that already. The class of file's owner is "ViewController" not UIViewController. And none of the IBOutlets have a name like "string".

Answer (score 0):

That error is occurring because your nib is trying to set a value onto an instance of a class that doesn't have a property by the name `basicPicker`. This is a solid indication that you're sending messages to the wrong type of object.

You need set the class of your `File's Owner` in your nib files to be the new UIViewController subclass you have created and not just the default UIViewController. Select `File's Owner` in your nib and you can change it in the right panel 'Utilities' third tab named **Identity Inspector** in Xcode, right at the top.